# Какой смысл создавать индекс для этого столбца?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, index

Занимаюсь по учебнику, в нем рассказывается про создание таблиц и индексов. Есть таблица classics, содержащая имена авторов, названия книг, жанр и года издания книг. Она содержит четыре столбца:
`author (VARCHAR(128)
 title (VARCHAR(128))
 category (VARCHAR(16))
 year (CHAR(4))`

Далее, в учебнике создаются индексы для этих столбцов
`ALTER TABLE classics ADD INDEX(author(20))
 ALTER TABLE classics ADD INDEX(title(20))
 ALTER TABLE classics ADD INDEX(category(4))
 ALTER TABLE classics ADD INDEX(year)`
Я понимаю зачем создавать индексы для столбцов author, title и category - для того, чтобы сократить размер данных в индексе и ускорить доступ к БД.
**Но зачем создавать индекс для year, если я не ограничиваю его размер? Да и тем более его размер ограничить нельзя, т.к. год состоит из четырех цифр. Зачем тогда создавать индекс для year?  В чем смысл? Ведь насколько я понимаю, я не получу никакой прибавки к производительности.**

Comment: Как, по-вашему, связан индекс и ограничение размера столбца? Почему эти параметры вообще как-то должны быть связаны между собой?

Comment: [Индексы в базах данных: назначение](http://www.askit.ru/custom/db_basics/m6/06_01_indexes_basics.htm)

Comment: @СергейМишин получается, что INDEX ускоряют доступ к БД не только за счет ограничения размеров данных?

Comment: @СергейМишин Т.е. индекс сам по себе изначально ускоряет доступ к БД?

Comment: "Индекс формируется из значений одного или нескольких столбцов таблицы и указателей на соответствующие строки таблицы и, таким образом, позволяет искать строки, удовлетворяющие критерию поиска. Ускорение работы с использованием индексов достигается в первую очередь за счёт того, что индекс имеет структуру, оптимизированную под поиск — например, сбалансированного дерева" (c) wikipedia . Причем тут ограничение размера данных? Забудьте вы про свои ограничения размеров данных.

Comment: Ограничение индекса позволяет лишь сэкономить места на диске для хранения индексов (см http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/CREATE_INDEX.html с примером `name(10)`)

Comment: `Т.е. индекс сам по себе изначально ускоряет доступ к БД?` - и да и нет. Да - помогают ускорить за счёт алгоритма. Нет не помогают, потому что можно так обвешать БД индексами и нерационально использовать, что можно наоборот, всё только замедлить

Comment: @СергейМишин теперь вроде понятно) Спасибо